# Looking for (some) l3box equivalents of graphics' \resizebox variants

Tags: expl3

AFAIK, the box resizing functions of the `l3box` module are implemented using the LaTeX2e `graphics`package.

However, some of the `\resizebox` variants don't have an `expl3` counterpart.

The available ones are:

```
\resizebox*{<h-size>}{<v-size>} --> \box_resize:Nnn<boxnum>{<h-size>}{<v-size>}
\resizebox*{!}{<v-size>}        --> \box_resize_to_ht_plus_dp:Nn<boxnum>{<v-size>}
\resizebox{<h-size>}{!}         --> \box_resize_to_wd:Nn<boxnum>{<h-size>}
```

But I am looking for

```
\resizebox{<h-size>}{<v-size>}  --> ? resizes width and height *
\resizebox{!}{<v-size>}         --> ? resizes height, while maintaining aspect ratio **
```

`*)` Something like `\box_resize_to_wd_and_ht:Nnn<boxnum>{<h-size>}{<v-size>}`, because existing `\box_resize:Nnn` is essentially `\box_resize_to_wd_and_ht_plus_dp:Nnn`

**) The latter of the missing mappings could be named as `\box_resize_to_ht:Nn<boxnum>{<v-size>}`.

Is there a reason why they are not provided? Could they be added in a future `expl3` version?

Comment: Not sure this is really a question: more something for discussion on LaTeX-L. (I note in particular that these functions are marked as _experimental_ at least in part as at the moment feedback has been somewhat limited!) Also, it's not `<boxnum>` but `<box>` (yes I know boxes have to be handled by number but we don't support _e.g._ `\box_resize:Nnn 20 ...`)

Comment: @Joseph Ok, I have just sent a request to LaTeX-L.

Comment: @JosephWright @AlexG Should we close this question as both requested control sequences appear in a current `interfcae3.pdf`?

Comment: @HenriMenke. Yes, I agree.

Comment: The feature request resulting from this question has been fulfilled.